# OpenAI Fine tuned engine not working in Node - "Engine not found"

Tags: node.js, openai-api

I have fine-tuned an engine on OpenAI using my own data. I can access the engine in the Playground with no issues, however, when I try to access it programmatically using Node & the openai Node library, I get an "Engine not found" error. The weird thing is, I could have sworn it worked before.

Anyway, here is my code:

```js
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
async function getDream() {
  const completion = await openai.createCompletion("davinci:ft-personal-2022-04-09-19-12-54", {
  prompt: "I dreamed",
});
  console.log(completion.data.choices[0].text);
}

getDream();
```

Here's the error:

```
error: {
        message: 'Engine not found',
        type: 'invalid_request_error',
        param: null,
        code: null
      }
```

I tried running the same code but with a regular engine (davinci). Works fine that way. I've double-checked that I have the name of my fine-tuned engine right and tried it using the engine ID just in case. Nothing seems to work.

PS - I have run this using the OpenAI CLI as well using `openai api completions.create -m davinci:ft-personal-2022-04-09-19-12-54 -p "I dreamed"` and that works as well.

Answer (score 6):

I'm back, answering my own question in hopes that it will help others.

It seems that if you are using your own fine-tuned model, you have to use a different method than if you use one of the default models. Instead of `createCompletion`, you should use `createCompletionFromModel`. So the function above (`getDream`) should actually look like this:

```js
async function getDream() {
  const response = await openai.createCompletionFromModel({
    model: 'davinci:ft-personal-2022-04-09-19-12-54',
    prompt: 'I dreamed'
    // add other parameters here
  });
}
```

You can add other completion parameters to this below `prompt`, e.g. `temperature`, `frequency_penalty`, etc.